# Ruby on Rails: The same check in multiple actions in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, model-view-controller

Frstly my apologies if this is a duplicate question.  I have tried to find the answer but as Im very new to Rails I did not know what to search for.

I have a controller that has some security on it.  For the show, edit, update and destroy actions I need to check if the user owns the persona they are working on, like this:

```
if @persona.user_id != @current_user.id

  flash[:notice] = "Sorry, we couldn't find that persona"
  redirect_to '/personas/'

else

  # do something else
```

This is relatively easy.  However, how do I do this in a DRY way?  The code before the else is repeated across all 4 actions, the code after the else statement will be different on a per controller basis.

Thanks in advance.

Richard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use a `before_filter`. Something like this:

```
class PersonasController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_owner, :only => [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show
  #...
  end

  #...etc.

  protected

  def check_owner
    redirect_to personas_path unless params[:id] == current_user.id
  end
end
```

Also, take @davidb's advice on writing a `current_user` method if you don't already have one, which will go in your application_controller.rb. Something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :current_user

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= session[:user_id] ? User.find(session[:user_id]) : User.new
  end
end
```

You may have to tweak all of this, since it will depend on how you have your models setup. This is just a general idea of what you need to/should do.

Answer (score 1):

Use `before_filter` here is an overview:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters

To dry it you should also write a `current_user` method that returns the logged in user!

Answer (score 0):

You can move your security logic to the before_filter. It will run before your actions and make your security check.

Your controller file:

```
class TestController

   before_filter :check_persona, :only => [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

   private

      def check_persona
         if @persona.user_id != @current_user.id
            flash[:notice] = "Sorry, we couldn't find that persona"
            redirect_to '/personas/'
         end
      end

end
```

Comment: This likely won't work since `@persona` is likely set in the method after the `before_filter` is called.

Comment: It can be loaded in before_filter, too.